Why my Node.js v18 Needs ipv4first for Connection Issues?
I encountered the following error when starting my Node.js server running on version 18:
ERROR - An unhandled exception has occurred. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
I resolved the issue by adding this code:
import { setDefaultResultOrder } from 'node:dns';

setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');

However, I have a couple of questions:

Why was my service attempting to connect using IPv4 instead of IPv6? (thus, I needed to specify for it to work with "ipv4first")
Why does this problem not occur with Node.js v20 on another service?

